# AlwaysOn database not synchronizing/recovery pending due to cluster loss quorum

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups, clustering

I have this error in cluster event

> 'Cluster node 'MMPDB1NEW' was removed from the active failover cluster membership. The Cluster service on this node may have stopped. This could also be due to the node having lost communication with other active nodes in the failover cluster'

But now even though my cluster nodes are online and quorum is healthy, still my node 2 database is showing not synchronizing/Recovery pending and in AlwaysOn health events I can see:

> 'A connection for availability group 'MTCBAG' from availability replica 'node1' with id.. to 'node 2' with id.. has been successfully established.

Should I need to wait until it synchronizes back or anything need to be done to bring back my secondary node?

Answer (score 0):

This issue solved after click on resume data movement in node 2 . Hope it helps others.